# Adobe Air - IP to location

Tags: apache-flex, air, geolocation

Is there a way to get the broad position of a user based on the IP address? (I'm building an Adobe Air desktop app for notebook users)

Comment: I'm going to do a bit of exploration on this issue, but I believe since you're going to be running in the context of a desktop application you may need to rely on an external service to provide the information.  It appears the AIR geolocation APIs only work for devices with geolocation sensors (GPS or wireless access point based).  Within an HTML5 context you could use the geoloc APIs there and ExternalInterface... here's a free limited use service http://www.geoio.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried out http://www.netimpact.com/, like you were looking for it's broad position, it placed me 3.7 miles away from my actual location, seems relatively simple to use and can respond with delimited data that can be split using the split method or else can choose to get JSON encoded object data which can be easily read into an AS3 object in Flex using JSON.parse().  Be sure to read up the FAQ on their site to get a better understanding of how they retrieve the data and what the accuracy is generally like, they allow 1000 requests per developer per day if you need more they have pricing starting at 20 bucks a month.

NOTE: Netimpact has shut down and they migrated users to their new provider, [KickFire](https://kickfire.com/kf-api). They've also broadened their offering to include not only IP2GEO, but also IP2Company, & Domain2IP.

**EDIT:**

A bit more information on exploring this further and some sample code.  So the only problem I'm seeing with my solution is getting the WAN IP address, I think you'll need to use some sort of server side script to bounce back the users external IP in order to make this work entirely.  I attempted using the NetworkInfo but this will always be reporting based on LAN IP addresses which won't work for the geoip look-up.  So this leads me to using PHP or some other server side script for obtaining the IP.  Further discussion on getting the IP using PHP here:
http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10327697

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

            private const MY_API_KEY:String = "PUT YOUR OWN KEY HERE";

            [Bindable]
            private var ipLookupResult:Object;

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var httpService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
                httpService.url = "http://api.geoio.com/q.php?key="+MY_API_KEY+"&qt=geoip&d=json&q=PUT_YOUR_IP_HERE";
                httpService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, lookupResultHandler);
                httpService.send();
            }
            private function lookupResultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                ipLookupResult = JSON.parse(event.result as String);
            }

            protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                for each(var ni:NetworkInterface in NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces())
                {
                    var addresses:Vector.<InterfaceAddress> = ni.addresses;
                    var userIp:String = addresses[0].address;
                    trace(userIp);
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Button click="button1_clickHandler(event)" label="Look me up"/>
    <s:Form>
        <s:FormItem label="City">
            <s:Label text="{ipLookupResult[0][0]}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="State">
            <s:Label text="{ipLookupResult[0][1]}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Country">
            <s:Label text="{ipLookupResult[0][2]}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="ISP">
            <s:Label text="{ipLookupResult[0][3]}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Latitude">
            <s:Label text="{ipLookupResult[0][4]}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Longitude">
            <s:Label text="{ipLookupResult[0][5]}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Country Code">
            <s:Label text="{ipLookupResult[0][6]}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

If you don't have access to write your own server side scripts you can also look to external services to obtain the information, I believe whatismyip.com offers this but not sure about licensing/cost and I know they specifically don't want you to use the main page to scrape out the IP (there's undoubtedly some free version of this service available if they charge).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and example. Do you have some experience with MaxMind? http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity - Is that one free if I host it on my own server? That way I could lookup the IP and get the users location, right?

Comment: Well geoip is free unless you believe you'll go beyond 1000 look-ups per day, both seem to fulfill the same purpose though of lookup based on IP, only difference would be it appears you could host the IP database yourself using what they provide and therefore make one call in which the users external/WAN IP is resolved and then used for the look-up but the time difference is probably negligible and you'll save a lot of time not dealing with the DB (getting updates) directly and leaving it to a third party service.

Comment: I'd still personally probably try to go with just writing up the simple server side script to return the clients IP then make the call to geoip for the reverse look-up, but if you want to do the extra work of setting up the DB and connecting their provided code objects to the DB it's a viable solution as well.  It appears it will cost more in the long run as well http://www.maxmind.com/app/builder